# How do I delete folder that that was synced with Onedrive but refused to stop syncing?

Tags: onedrive

There is this project folder that I am trying to delete but it keeps denying me even after I ran `rm -force`. It shows me this instead:

```
is an NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify this object.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm .\db\
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\KenGon...git\objects\db\:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

.

```
rm : There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point
At line:1 char:1
+ rm .\db\ -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

When is move into the folder, and tried to list the folder contents, it shows me this instead:

```
ls : The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\KenGon....git\objects\db:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Is there any way in which I can delete this folder? I have already stopped syncing with OneDrive and restarted it multiple times. The advice I found on Microsoft's forums does not seem to help. Even after pausing the sync, the folders still show a blue circular arrows - still syncing?

Answer (score 2):

It is dumb, but I ran `chkdsk /f /r` and had to hard force reboot my computer. Not sure what the exact error was that caused the folder to be immutable. Seems to be some corrupted data when I tried to remove OneDrive while it was syncing, causing some problems.

Comment: It fixed it for me. There seems to be a problem when syncing folders that keeps you from deleting them or even going into them showing the error "tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid". Running this command as admin fixes it. Be aware it requires a restart and can take a few hours to complete.

Comment: confirmed to be working

Answer (score 1):

Alternative and potentially faster solution: Use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), change to directory and delete files/folders

```
rm -r -f mybrokenfolder
```